# How to load a dynamic page into an iframe

Tags: jquery, dom, iframe

I created an iframe and set the source to an empty page which is already created too. The problem is how to dynamically add some html chunk (the html is already stored in a variable) inside a div on the empty page and then display it on the iframe. I'm using jquery. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the iframe, then use `.contents()` to access the jQuery-wrapped document object of the iframe (same domain-only!).

```
var chunk = "<a>Test</a>";

var iframeBody = $("#id-selector-of-iframe").contents().find("body");
iframeBody.append(chunk);
//Or, if you want to overwrite the body:
//iframeBody.html(chunk);
```

Comment: I was halfway through writing an answer using the "contentDocument" property.  Yours is better.